# The attributes of my child class are lazily initialized

Tags: c++

I have created a parent class in C++ and one child class which I have two attributes: `_trigger` and `_echo`. In order to use my child class I declare it and I assign its address to a pointer of the parent class. Hence, I use the methods of my parent class.

My problem: When I use the method `cyclePulse` without parameters (`int trigger, int echo`) and the attributes from my class (`_trigger` and `_echo`), the method does not work properly. I guess it is because the attributes `_trigger` and `_echo` are lazily initialized, or because I am not using `new` keyword when I am creating my object.

```
class ISensor {
...
public:
    ISensor();
    virtual ~ISensor();
    ...
    virtual int connect() = 0;
    virtual char * readRequest() = 0;
    virtual int disconnect() = 0;
};

class HCSR04: public ISensor {
private:
    int _trigger;
    int _echo;
public:
    HCSR04();
    HCSR04(int trigger, int echo);
    ...
    int connect();
    char * readRequest();
    uint64_t cyclePulse(int trigger, int echo);
    float distanceCentimeters();
};
```

Here is the implementation of HCSR04.cpp. **Edited:** I forgot the constructors.

```
HCSR04::HCSR04() {
    _echo = RPI_V2_GPIO_P1_13;
    _trigger = RPI_V2_GPIO_P1_15;
}
HCSR04::HCSR04(int trigger, int echo) {
    _echo = echo;
    _trigger = trigger;
}    
char * HCSR04::readRequest() {
    float preCent = distanceCentimeters();
    char* buf = new char[20];
    sprintf(buf, "%.10f", preCent);
    return buf;
}
float HCSR04::distanceCentimeters() {
    return (float) cyclePulse(_trigger, _echo) / 55.5;
}
uint64_t HCSR04::cyclePulse(int trigger, int echo) {
    uint64_t width, begin, start, end;
    int max = 80, check;

    begin = bcm2835_st_read();

    // Emit pulse for 10 microseconds
    bcm2835_gpio_write(_trigger, HIGH); // Set trigger state HIGH
    bcm2835_delayMicroseconds(10);  // Wait 10 microseconds
    bcm2835_gpio_write(_trigger, LOW);  // Set trigger state LOW

    while (bcm2835_gpio_lev(_echo) == LOW && check < max) {
        start = bcm2835_st_read();
        check = (int) begin - start;
    }
    while (bcm2835_gpio_lev(_echo) == HIGH) {
        bcm2835_delayMicroseconds(1);
    }
    end = bcm2835_st_read();

    width = end - start;

    return width;
}
```

I am using the class like this:

```
HCSR04 deviceUltrasonic;
ISensor * sensorUltrasonic = &deviceUltrasonic;
char* readRequestArray = sensorUltrasonic->readRequest();
```

Comment: `HCSR04`s constructors?

Comment: In the constructor that doesn't take any parameters, what are you setting `_trigger` and `_echo` to?

Comment: I edited the message. Sorry about that. I forgot the constructors. But I am initializing the attr on the constructors.

Comment: What means not work properly? and how is work properly?

Comment: The first time that I return the value from distanceCentimeters, it is completely wrong. I suppose it is because the `_tigget` and `_echo` were not initialized. If I print the values of `_tigget` and `_echo`, the function return correct values. Moreover, the second time that I execute the function it works properly.

Comment: I don't see any lazy initialization in your code. But you are using `check` uninitialized in the `cyclePulse` method. That could lead to an early call to `bcm2835_st_read`

Comment: The explicit cast in `check = (int) begin - start;` ends up not doing anything (assuming `sizeof(int) <= sizeof(uint64_t)`): the compiler will just convert the int value back to `uint64_t` before subtracting.

Comment: How come `cyclePulse` does not use its parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving my previous comment as a possible answer here, because I assume that the uninitialized variables are causing your fault here:

```
uint64_t HCSR04::cyclePulse(int trigger, int echo) {
    uint64_t width, begin, start, end;
    int max = 80, check = 0;  // <<< init check to 0. 
                              // Btw: size_t or any other unsigned type matches
                              // better the purpose of what you want to achieve.

    begin = bcm2835_st_read();

    // begin is not used afterwards. Did you mean to initialize "start" here?
    start = begin;

    // Emit pulse for 10 microseconds
    bcm2835_gpio_write(_trigger, HIGH); // Set trigger state HIGH
    bcm2835_delayMicroseconds(10);  // Wait 10 microseconds
    bcm2835_gpio_write(_trigger, LOW);  // Set trigger state LOW

    while (bcm2835_gpio_lev(_echo) == LOW && check < max) {
        start = bcm2835_st_read();
        check = (int) begin - start;
    }
    while (bcm2835_gpio_lev(_echo) == HIGH) {
        bcm2835_delayMicroseconds(1);
    }
    end = bcm2835_st_read();

    width = end - start;

    return width;
}
```